# What is "Active down-programmer"?

Tags: power-supply

All I can find online is explanations like this:

> When a power supply with current sink capability is programmed to a
> voltage level less than that actually at the output terminals it will
> automatically begin to sink current. The down-programmer can be thought
> of as an internal load across the power supply's output terminals that
> helps bring the output voltage down quickly.

But how does it actually work? is there a mosfet as a load? what about the current this "load" is drawing, is it being nulled by the ammeter?

Can someone please open this up a little with an schematic and/or working principles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that the power supply regulator output has a push-pull stage, like an opamp would, but stronger.

Normal voltage regulators only implement a push stage.

If you have pushbutton to set regulator feedback so that the output would jump from 5V to 10V, the push stage would quickly react and step the voltage from 5V to 10V as fast as it can.

But as a normal regulator does not have a pull stage, using the pushbutton to change output voltage from 10V to 5V would just cause the voltage to slowly go down as the load consumes current from the output capacitor, before the voltage settles at 5V level.

So a regulator with active pull stage, it would work like an op-amp, and quicky set the output voltage from 10V to 5V, discharging the output capacitor rapidly, regardless of load.

Comment: Stupid question; why they don't use a heavy load at the output to draw like 20mA and/or smaller output capacitor?

Comment: Why would they? I would not call 20mA a heavy load. It might still be too slow for some application. And it would consume some energy and heat up. And the circuits need some amount of output capacitance to make the system stable. It's really the same thing that is inside any amplifier that drives a speaker, it can raise and lower the voltage rapidly, and some power supplies need that, for example if you are testing what kind of disturbances your device can accept at the power input.